# variable length arguments with generic types scala

Tags: scala, generics, variadic-functions, abstract-data-type

I have a simple abstract data type, a tree.

```
sealed trait Tree[A]
case object EmptyTree extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Node[A](op: A => A, branches: List[Tree[A]]) extends Tree[A]
```

How can i make the operation that a `Node` holds to accept a variable length number of arguments of type A?

An exemple:

```
def printAll(strings: String*) {
  strings.foreach(println)
}
```

`printAll` receives a variable number of strings.

In the same way i wanted to make my Tree to hold an operation `op` of the type `A* => A`.

A possible way would be to make it receive a `List[A]`, but i wonder if there isn't a more direct way of doing this.

---

by the way can i also turn `branches: List[Tree[A]]` into something like `branches: Tree[A]*`. Does this make sense from a design perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Seq in the signature, then you will be able to pass varargs functions

```
sealed trait Tree[A]
case object EmptyTree extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Node[A](op: Seq[A] => A, branches: List[Tree[A]]) extends Tree[A]

object Test {
  Node[String](test[String], List())

  def test[A](elem: A*): A = ???
}
```

Comment: going to test it, it makes sense, than you for your answer

Comment: by the way, can i also make `branches: List[Tree[A]])` like `branches: Tree[A]*`.

Does this make sense from a design perspective?

Comment: The varargs makes sense when you want to have a function that accepts n elements as parameter, but it makes less sense when you are declaring the fields of a class. But it's up to you to use it.